# Insert CSV file from FTP to MySQL using Mulesoft

Tags: mysql, ftp, mule, mule-studio

I am still new at Mulesoft EE. I need to get CSV file from FTP server (Filezilla) and insert it into MySQL database (Wamp).

I want to run this test code (I replaced the FTP with HTTP in order to test) but postman plugin shows no results!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:...>
    <db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="localhost"
        port="3306"   database="information"
        doc:name="MySQL Configuration" />
    <data-mapper:config name="CSV_To_XML" transformationGraphPath="csv_to_xml.grf" doc:name="CSV_To_XML"/>
    <jdbc-ee:mysql-data-source name="MySQL_Data_Source" user="User" password="Pass" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/information" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="MySQL Data Source"/>
    <jdbc-ee:connector name="Database" dataSource-ref="MySQL_Data_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database"/>
    <flow name="dbFlow1" doc:name="dbFlow1">
 <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="8084" path="csv" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="CSV_To_XML" doc:name="CSV To XML"/>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
        <foreach collection="#[xpath('//info')]" doc:name="For Each">
            <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
            <db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO `information`.`user_table`
(`current_date`,
`serialnumber`,
`gender`,
`fullname`,
`birthdate`,
`email`,
`mobilnumber`,
`address`)
VALUES
(#[xpath://date],
#[xpath://serialnumber],
#[xpath://gender],
#[xpath://fullname],
#[xpath://birthdate],
#[xpath://email],
#[xpath://mobilenumber],
#[xpath://address]
);]]></db:parameterized-query>
            </db:insert>
            <message-properties-transformer scope="invocation" doc:name="Message Properties">
                <add-message-property key="count" value="#[flowVars.counter]"/>
            </message-properties-transformer>
        </foreach>
        <logger message="#[payload] Number of records #[flowVars.count]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="localhost" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Could you come up with an example of the file you want to load from FTP and the DB schema you want to store information to?

Comment: @brazo the .txt file, has a heading row, with:
date|serialnumber|gender|fullname|birthdate|email|mobilenumber|address
then  all the names rows under this heading. the DB has same colomns.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey Mate, you added the following lines:
    <jdbc-ee:mysql-data-source name="MySQL_Data_Source"  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/information" ...
    <jdbc-ee:connector dataSource-ref="MySQL_Data_Source" ... 

Do you run EE (enterprise) version of Mule? The jdbc-ee connector configuration is also not used in your flow. Double click on MySQL Configuration in Mule Studio Connections Explorer and press "Test Connection".
Also you are still using my database "information" which I assume is wrong for your setting.

I assume you can delete jdbc-ee and correct your connection settings.

Comment: 1. If you have Enterprise Edition then use MuleSofts premium level support. You will get a help immediately. 2. If you pressed "test connection" and it said tested successfully then your driver and config seems correct. What is the name of your driver? For MySQL just Google MySQL jdbc driver.

Comment: If you are a paying enterprise customer you can take your telephone and call MuleSoft support... Did you actually start the flow via Run button on studio? You can also start it in Debug and set a breakpoint at the Http inbound endpoint and watch what happens in Mule.

Comment: Please try to start learning about Mule. It is documented in a very great and structured way. You also can find a lot of videos.
Start here for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zv0dO-5wT8w

Additionally, try the free online training - Mule Fundamentals: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Fundamentals

Comment: @brazo sorry if annoying, but did you try your XML on your local machine? I think the issue is from the flow not from my side! the connection with db is correct, but no query in the xml, so nothing is inserting even if not using the FTP. Could you please double check?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it works. I assumed a specific file input, please try with it from my answer. It won't work if your input file looks different. The MEL expressions in the DB connector retrieve the information to be inserted into DB from the payload. Please make sure you read the MuleSoft documentation about MEL too. I hope that helps you getting further.

Comment: @brazo, I've upvoted your answer as it's really working now, except with Date values. mule is showing:== birthdate (date) cannot be set to "12-03-70" - doesn't match defined format "" in record 1, field 5 ("birthdate"), metadata "mytest"; value: '12-03-70' Unparseable date: "12-03-70" at position 8== where "my test" is the name of the csv file. however, when I put all Date cells empty in the file, other data are inserted correctly!! the date cells are showing NULL in DB. So, only Date type has problem, Do you think it's related with Mysql date format? Big thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey Jad, please accept my answer also as correct. Yes, it seems to be the date format - see here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html

Comment: You need a set payload component before SMTP endpoint that takes the value from the count variable and adds it as message payload. I updated my answer. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see if the following helps you. Just replace my File connector with your FTP one, should work.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:smtp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp/current/mule-smtp.xsd">
    <db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="localhost"
        port="3306" user="" password="" database="information"
        doc:name="MySQL Configuration" />
    <data-mapper:config name="CSV_To_XML" transformationGraphPath="csv_to_xml.grf" doc:name="CSV_To_XML"/>
    <flow name="stackoverflow-ftp-dbFlow1" doc:name="stackoverflow-ftp-dbFlow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" />
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="CSV_To_XML" doc:name="CSV To XML"/>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
        <foreach collection="#[xpath('//info')]" doc:name="For Each">
            <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
            <db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO `information`.`user_table`
(`current_date`,
`serialnumber`,
`gender`,
`fullname`,
`birthdate`,
`email`,
`mobilnumber`,
`address`)
VALUES
(#[xpath://date],
#[xpath://serialnumber],
#[xpath://gender],
#[xpath://fullname],
#[xpath://birthdate],
#[xpath://email],
#[xpath://mobilenumber],
#[xpath://address]
);]]></db:parameterized-query>
            </db:insert>
            <message-properties-transformer scope="invocation" doc:name="Message Properties">
                <add-message-property key="count" value="#[flowVars.counter]"/>
            </message-properties-transformer>
        </foreach>
        <logger message="#[payload] Number of records #[flowVars.count]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-payload value="#[flowVars.count]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="localhost" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I used the DataMapper feature in [Anypoint Studio 3.5 of MuleSoft](https://www.mulesoft.com/platform/mule-studio) to actually make the mapping from your CSV to XML that I use in the flow.
There you can just set the example file of your csv as input example, and the xml as output example.

I used the following files assuming the little information you offered...

Users csv as Input format example for DataMapper:

```
date|serialnumber|gender|fullname|birthdate|email|mobilenumber|address
03-07-2014|129329|m|your name|12-03-1970|my@mail.com|219239|my address
04-07-2014|129329|w|her name|12-03-1975|her@mail.com|219229|her address
```

User XML I as Output format example for DataMapper **Attention: The flow variables and xpath expressions depend on it!!**

```
<infos>
    <info>
        <date></date>
        <serialnumber></serialnumber>
        <gender></gender>
        <fullname></fullname>
        <birthdate></birthdate>
        <email></email>
        <mobilenumber></mobilenumber>
        <address></address>
    </info>
    <info>
        <date></date>
        <serialnumber></serialnumber>
        <gender></gender>
        <fullname></fullname>
        <birthdate></birthdate>
        <email></email>
        <mobilenumber></mobilenumber>
        <address></address>
    </info>
</infos>
```

Good luck!

PS: Don't forget to add the mysql lib to your classpath or maven.

Comment: You can replace the File/FTP with a HTTP inbound endpoint that you can send your csv file to.
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="8084" path="csv" doc:name="HTTP"/>

Just use postman plugin for chrome or curl to send your csv file as POST request to http://localhost:8084/csv

Comment: Mate, you have to work on your information policy. Please put some time in exact descriptions of your issue. What did you do? What is showing the exception? How to reproduce? Please add Mule console output. Did you start your flow in Studio? Did you do a POST? That's the only way one can efficiently help you. Cheers.

Comment: Please post your DB configuration here. Did you try "test connection" button after configuring it in Studio?